# pgAdmin4 combines geometry SRID and type

Tags: postgis, pgadmin-3

Using `PostGIS`, I have a table with a geometry of `LineStringZ` with SRID `28356`. In `pgAdminIII` (v1.22.2) its definition in the SQL pane shows as:

```
geom geometry(LineStringZ,28356)
```

In `pgAdmin4` (v4.1) the exact same table's SQL definitions shows as:

```
geom geometry(7259142)
```

Another table with the same SRID but a `PointZ` type shows in pgAdminIII as:

```
geom geometry(PointZ,28356)
```

And in pgAdmin4 as:

```
geom geometry(7259138)
```

Assuming this is a feature, not a bug, it looks as though `pgAdmin4` is combining the `type` and `SRID` into a single "code", e.g. `(LineStringZ,28356) --> 7259142`, but I can't find information on how this is performed. I have 2 questions:

1. How is this new "code" calculated?
2. Is there a way to show the `type` and `SRID` in `pgAdmin4`, just like it was in `pgAdminIII`?

**Edited** to add my environment:

- `PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit`
- `POSTGIS="2.3.1 r15264" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11.99" TOPOLOGY RASTER`
- `pgAdmin4 v1.1 using python 2.7.12 and Flask 0.11.1`
- `pgAdminIII v1.22.2`

Comment: Not sure about pgAdmin4 but you get the srid of a geometry with [ST_SRID](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_SRID.html) and the type with [GeometryType](http://postgis.net/docs/GeometryType.html) or ST_GeometryType. To get all geometry columns consult the view public.geometry_columns where the srid and other typemods should appears

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In binary, `28356` is `0110 110 1100 0100` (hexadecimal `6E C4`)

In binary, `7259142` is `0110 110 1100 0100 0000 0110` (hexadecimal `6E C4 06`)

Therefore, it seems safe to assume that a bitwise right shift 8 will remove the SRID from the combined code, and a bitwise `AND` mask with `0x00FF` will capture the geometry type (though casting to `bit(8)` seems to be easier):

```
SELECT 7259142>>8 as srid, 7259142::bit(8) as type;

srid   type
28356  00000110
```

If you generate a number of different tables with different geometry types, you should be able to discern a bit(8) -> varchar(20) mapping `CASE` statement.

Comment: Well spotted @Vince! I am not sure how to convert the type into a human-readable string, e.g. _LineStringZ_, though. I hope pgAdmin4 can/will be edited to show this string + SRID instead of the combined integer.

Comment: @gep Please edit your question to specify the PostgreSQL and PostGIS versions in use. I'd need to replicate your environment to build a bit(8) mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the table in the column propriety you see the SRID.